I am need to get total count of terminated EC2 instances from Jan 1, 2024 until today
I am trying to get all the terminated instances for the past year and there a particular Name that I want to omit from being included in the count.  Here is the bash script that I tried and I am getting count of 0.  When I remove select(.tags[]?.key != "databricks") then i get the count.

MAX_RETRIES=5
RETRY_DELAY=5
RETRY_COUNT=0

while [ $RETRY_COUNT -lt $MAX_RETRIES ]; do
    aws cloudtrail lookup-events \
        --region us-east-1 \
        --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=TerminateInstances \
        --start-time 2024-01-01T00:00:00Z \
        --end-time 2024-12-10T23:59:59Z \
        --query 'Events[*].CloudTrailEvent' \
        --output json | tee terminated_instances.json | jq '[.[] | fromjson | .requestParameters.instancesSet.items[] | select(.tags[]?.key != "databricks") | .instanceId] | length'
    
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        break
    fi

    RETRY_COUNT=$((RETRY_COUNT + 1))
    echo "Retry $RETRY_COUNT/$MAX_RETRIES..."
    sleep $((RETRY_DELAY * RETRY_COUNT))
done

if [ $RETRY_COUNT -eq $MAX_RETRIES ]; then
    echo "Failed after $MAX_RETRIES attempts."
    exit 1
fi


The question title should be about the technical problem that prevented you from accomplishment your goal on your own, not a description of the goal itself. We want other people with the same problem to be able to find your question and learn from its answers even if they're writing a completely different kind of program.

(This is related to why [MRE] guidelines instruct you to come up with the shortest possible code that causes the same problem when run without changes -- it's unhelpful both to you and to future readers if people are spending time correcting other issues rather than focusing on the specific place where you got stuck).

In this particular case we should need nothing but a selected subset of the JSON file created by tee (created to be complete enough that jq can use it without errors other than your "real" problem and correct and incorrect output can be distinguished, but as short as possible given that), and the jq code; everything else is irrelevant.

There's no tags in the json output terminated_instances.json, that's why you're getting 0 when you try to count tags = "databricks"
CloudTrail Events: CloudTrail logs API calls and not the full instance details. In this case:

TerminateInstances event logs the instanceId and some other information, but does not include tags for the terminated instance.
Tags need to be fetched separately via the DescribeInstances API before termination.

and you can use describe-tags just with the current EC2s, not for an old deleted instance. so your script is just behaving as it should be. if you just run
aws cloudtrail lookup-events \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=TerminateInstances \
    --start-time 2024-01-01T00:00:00Z \
    --end-time 2024-12-10T23:59:59Z \
    --query 'Events[*].CloudTrailEvent' \
    --output json | tee terminated_instances.json

you will have the full json. and from that you can see that TAGS aren't included in the output.
